# Tile based map lags using a for-loop to draw, android game programming

Tags: java, android, 2d

I would like to know if anybody can help me with a better method of drawing a Tile map for my android game.

Currently, I use a for loop to draw the required Bitmaps to the screen but when doing this for the amount of tiles I need to render at once (enough to cover the screen and a bit more), when the map scrolls, you can notice the map become jolty with its movement, because of the for loop having to loop through all the tiles. The tiles are drawn simular to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 170; i++) {  
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x + i * bitmap.getWidth(), y, null);  
    }
```

The method I am currently using uses a few bitmaps to save memory, and draws them in different locations.

A different method i can think of to draw the map would be to create a larger Bitmap from the tiles and move the position of that larger bitmap to create movement. The problem with this is that is does require lots of memory and gets out of memory errors.

So, i need to try and find out a method of drawing multiple tiles preferably without the use of a for-loop (I believe the for-loop is causing the jolty, un-smooth movement of the map).

For more details just ask, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop is the correct way to draw it, your problem is probably the amount of data you are trying to draw in one frame and/or the number of pixels you are trying to push through the system.

If you want good performance on Android your best bet will be to use the graphics hardware it provides. There are various game frameworks available that will make that easier for you and give you much better performance than you will get otherwise.

If not then you will need to break up the drawing and still run the same effective logic but spread out so you draw a few tiles per frame.

Answer (score 0):

is it really required to draw ALL tiles at once?

if it is possible for you, maybe you can determine the 'visible view port' and then just draw those tiles, which need to be drawn?!?

```
int width = getWidth()/Tiles.width; // do it once before any rendering
                                    // thats the amount of tiles per line

int height = getHeight()/Tiles.height; // do it once before any rendering
                                       // thats the amount of tiles per row

Point pos = ...; // you should know the position of your 'figure' within the map
                 // could as well be the scroll position


//now draw only those tile from the 'viewport':    
for (int dy = 0; dy < width; dy++){
    for (int dx = 0; dy < height; dy++){
         int xOnMap = pos.x + x;
         int yOnMap = pos.y + dy;

         int index = yOnMap*height+yOnMap; //index in list

         canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 
             x * bitmap.getWidth(), y * bitMap.getHeight(), null);  
    }
}
```

so you just have to draw some tile and that would always be the same amount...

i must confess i wrote that code onstackoverflow so there is a chance i did a syntax terror ^^

Comment: Thanks this is what i will need to do